# How to load resources and use their data correctly? Godot 4.0.2 stable

Tags: godot, godot4

I know it should work. I followed KidsCanCode tutorial [here](https://kidscancode.org/godot_recipes/4.x/basics/file_io/index.html) and this video tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VGxYtJ3rXdE&ab_channel=Queble).

I use a `Resource` (previously `Node`) to store some data. It has some functions as well.

My problem is that when I load already saved resources (they save without any problems as `.res`) they are regarded as just `Resources`. In the video, the guy can access the resource's data by changing the value of 'health' parameter after loading the resource itself. In my case, I try to get some data out of my resource directly and get an error

> Invalid get index 'parameter_name' (on base: 'Resource')

Basically, the same as `playerData.health` from the video (parameter_name above would be `health`).

Exporting the variable does not help. I also tried opening them externally through text editing programs. If I use Windows' Notepad, I get some strange short one-liner with (I suppose) broken encoding. If I use Sublime Text, I get what appears to be something hashed, just a couple of rows and colums of numbers and letters.

Here's my code for saving/loading it:

```
ResourceSaver.save(my_resource, save_path)
if ResourceLoader.exists(save_path):
    my_newly_loaded_resource = ResourceLoader.load(save_path).duplicate(true)
var new_variable = my_newly_loaded_resource.parameter_name
```

What did I do wrong here? Do I need to additionally, kinda, "unpack" this resource maybe? As I understand, Godot tries to apply my original resource's parameter to it's own global `Resource` type. And, obviously, Godot's resource does not have what my resource had. Or should I just use the other way and save it as written in the [docs](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/io/saving_games.html)?

Comment: Please post the code of the custom resource type. Question: Is the code running in the editor (i.e. are you using `@tool`)? Note: The `.res` format is a binary format, if you want to be able to edit it with a text editor, save it as a `.tres` (the "t" stands for "text") - I don't think that is the issue at hand.

Comment: @Theraot It's literally just `class_name MyClassName extends Resource` plus a bunch of var's and func's. Running it in the scene (F6). Btw, I tried running the save function again (after restarting my pc and changing to `.tres`), and now it kinda saves, ie I can open it in the text editor, thank you for the clarification, but raises errors `Resource was not pre cached for the resource section, bug?`

Comment: I take it is not a `@tool` script, my guess for the "Invalid get index 'parameter_name'" error is that it was a typo (i.e. make sure it is also spelled `parameter_name` in the resource script). And about the cache bug, it might be an issue fixed in Godot 4.2. But here are a couple things to try: You can call `take_over_path` on the resource after saving it to force update the cache, or you can pass `ResourceLoader.CACHE_MODE_IGNORE` when loading so it does not read the resource from cache.

Comment: (1) @Theraot, so after digging some more, I found your comment [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/205217/save-and-load-resource-failing-with-error-constructing-a-gdscriptinstance). I had the same thing with `_init`. My bad( Now, to the interesting part. At one point it kind of started to load things, but it almost crashed my system due to running out of memory. And it also crashed WASAPI audio drivers in Godot.

Comment: (2) The drivers got fixed after a couple of restarts though. I also tried the other way around with json saving, but there appeared some problems with Vector2's, I tried Godot's `var_to_str` and reverse, it started crashing on saving stage again. So I will try packing everything into a single `PackedScene` tomorrow and see how it goes...